# SQL Server - selecting data where not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a way to be able to select from a table if that table doesn't contain data of a certain type.

For example if we have a table called `farm` and another table called `animal`.  Now FarmA contains a pig and a goat and FarmB just contains a goat.  I want to select all farms that contain no pigs.

My first try was to do this:
`SELECT f.*
FROM farm f
INNER JOIN animal a ON f.Id = a.FarmId
WHERE a.Name <> 'pig';`
 But this still returns me back FarmA because it contains a goat but I don't want it to return back any farms that have pigs.

I've tried some subquerys and used `not exists` but that didn't work either.  I'm sure this is easy I just can't structure my query right.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000976.html for a simple visual explanation of the different types of joins.

Comment: thanks for the link / now that i see the query it makes complete sense now / i appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select f.* 
from Farm f 
left outer join (
    select FarmID 
    from Animal 
    where Name = 'pig'    
) a on f.ID = a.FarmID 
where a.ID is null
```

Comment: I need this, but for multiple columns. Every time I try I get exponentially more records than I should. This is absolutely critical that I NOT have records which do not belong. Any ideas? I need rows which do not exist in another table with the same schema. They are before and after tables.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  I'm more familiar with Oracle but I checked and the "NOT EXISTS" syntax seems to be the same:

```
SELECT f.* FROM FARM f WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM animal a WHERE a.FarmId = f.FarmId and a.Name = 'pig')
```